# Why after upgrading to Next.js 13 from 12 I see a black strip on the side on mobil?

Tags: next.js, vercel

https://tikex-mongo-prod-4majnz7hm-j4nos.vercel.app

It look like this:

[image]

I did only bumped the next version number in package.json

When debugging it in cross device in Mac brower, I do not see any specific. it happens also in Chrome.

Comment: Your footer needs `overflow: hidden`. Also, maybe adjust your viewport meta tag to have `initial-scale=1` too.